# UIWebView on UITableViewCell drawing issue

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm using web view on table view cell to display formatted text. But web view displays content just after scrollDidEndDecelerating event, so web view is empty while table view is scrolling. I tried to call [cell setNeedsDisplay] on scrollDidScroll delegate event, but web view still empty. It looks ugly. Does anybody know any solution of this issue?

Thanks a lot,

Mitya

Answer (score 0):

try overriding the `-(void)drawRect` to render the text for the `UITableViewCell` using methods like `drawAtPoint:withFont`, `drawInRect:withFont:`and others. Then when the tableView scrolling ends, display your webview as normal. For more information, try:
http://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/fast-uitableviewcell-with-a-uiwebview/

Comment: Thanks for answer! Useful link, I thinked about such solution earlier, but this solution doesn't resolve the problem, it just allows to hide the problem as possible from user.